Why can't the constructor be called explicitly?
I was looking into creating a constructor to initialize an encapsulated std::array and came across a problem that the constructor of a copyable type (class A) could not be called explicitly. There are two cases in the given code. A simple example: an object of class B cannot explicitly call the copy constructor for a field of class A. And a complex one: the initialization of each element of the std::array requires an implicit call to the copy constructor. How can I avoid implicitly calling a copy constructor to initialize class members?
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
#include <utility> // std::forward
#include <array> // std::array

struct A {
  explicit A() = default;
  explicit A(A&) = default; // ERROR: used implicitly when initializing 'b'
};

struct B {
  //explicit B(A& a) : a_{a} {} // partially solves the problem, but cannot be defaulted
  A a_;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct C {
  template<class... Ts>
  explicit C(Ts&&... il) : values_{std::forward<Ts>(il)...} {} // how to use 'explicit A(A&)'?
  std::array<T, N> values_;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b{a}; // basic problem
  C<A, 3> c{a, a, a}; // extended problem
  return 0;
}


@JaMiT Why does B b{A{a}} work but not the original?

@DavidG "Why does B b{A{a}} work but not the original?" -- I don't know (which is another reason I cannot turn that into a good answer). Maybe something involving copy elision comes into play once an explicit copy has been made? I was just experimenting with how the call to the copy constructor could be made explicit, and this worked.

Why is the copy constructor explicit to begin with? This sounds more like a XY problem then anything else.

@JaMiT See guaranteed copy elision. values_{T{std::forward<Ts>(il)}...} is also the correct thing to do.

Constructors cannot be called directly in c++.

@JaMiT I've added links that address the side effects of solving the question posed. Initializing an encapsulated array was covered in the question.

@JaMiT A simple example identifies a problem that could not be solved, a complex example identifies the place where it was applied. The question to be solved is "how to avoid calling a constructor implicitly if the constructor itself is declared explicit"?

@PasserBy The problem is that while an individual class member can be initialized explicitly using the constructor's initialization list, each element of the encapsulated array can only be initialized implicitly.

Did you read the link to XY problem?

@PasserBy To avoid the "XY problem", I will clarify the statement of the problem I need to solve. I have legacy code that describes a class. All constructors of this class are declared explicit. I need to write a wrapper class for an std::array of objects of such a class, specifying an initializing constructor for this encapsulated array. Due to the legacy class's explicit constructor, I am unable to perform this initialization, which leads me to the question I asked.

@JaMiT Thank you for your remarks. You were right: I corrected the links in the text. I also think that the answer to my question can be covered in detail in the next topic.

@ValeriyKarasikov Since you're new, I'll point out that there is a "delete" link visible when hovering over your own comments. This can be used to clean up the comment section when certain comments no longer apply / have been addressed. I've done that for some of my comments; you might (up to you) want to do the same for some of yours, especially the replies to the comments I deleted. ;)

You can avoid implicitly calling a copy constructor by explicitly calling it. More commonly, this would be called explicitly making a copy, as in using A{a} to explicitly create a (temporary) copy of a.
B b{A{a}}; // basic problem
//  ^^ ^

For the template, I'll add a warning!
You can use the same technique when constructing an array, but first consider if you should. Adding generic code to handle a special case (when T is A) can have unforeseen consequences (when T is not A). Before modifying the constructor of C<>, you should find out why the copy constructor of A is explicit. One possibility is that copying A is supported, but expensive, hence each copy needs to be explicitly approved. Is this a valid place to approve copying A? Is it a valid place to approve copying any type with an explicit copy constructor?
Rather than modifying the template, it might be better to give A a (non-explicit) move constructor, which is another way to address an expensive-to-copy type. With a move constructor, you could apply the technique inside the main function, where you know you are dealing with A objects (and not some other type that should not be implicitly copied).
struct A {
  explicit A() = default;
  explicit A(A&) = default;
  A(A&&) = default;  // <--- Added a move constructor
};

C<A, 3> c{A{a}, A{a}, A{a}}; // extended problem
//        ^^ ^  ^^ ^  ^^ ^

Still, for completeness, if you are dead-set on making the template work, the technique can be applied there (no need to make explicit copies in main when initializing c).
// I don't recommend this, but it does compile:
explicit C(Ts&&... il) : values_{T{std::forward<Ts>(il)}...} {} // how to use 'explicit A(A&)'?
//                               ^^                    ^

Why does this work?
Isn't there still a copy from the temporary? Not as of C++17. Explicitly making a copy results in a prvalue, and a prvalue is not yet a materialized object. So when your A objects are initialized from these prvalues, the prvalues are materialized directly in the A objects; there is no additional copy. It's as if the prvalue tells the compiler how to construct an object, while the variable name tells the compiler where to construct it. In B b{A{a}}, the prvalue is A{a}, which explicitly says to make a copy, while the b names the place where the copy is to be made.
This is the same mechanism that gave us guaranteed copy elision (when returning a temporary object from a function).

I still get confused with prvalue materialization. If that part of my answer is off-base, let me know and I'll delete (or correct) that part.

You can use a pointer to do this:
struct B {
  std::unique_ptr<A> a_;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct C {
  template<class... Ts>
  explicit C(Ts&&... il) : values_{std::make_unique<A>(std::forward<Ts>(il))...} {}
  std::array<std::unique_ptr<T>, N> values_;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b{std::make_unique<A>(a)};
  C<A, 3> c{a, a, a};
}

